# APC is not running even after copying the php_apc.dll and changing the php.ini

Tags: php, apc, wampserver

I have a problem with PHP and APC...I want to design a MVC website with Symfony framework.So I tried to install APC extension on my current php version....I am using x64 version of WAMP Server with PHP 5.3.10 and Apache 2.0 on an x64 laptop...
I have copied the x64 version of php_apc.dll file into ext folder and uncomment the correspondin extension line in php.ini file...but when I open apc.php file in browser it says : "No cache info available. APC does not appear to be running.". Also in my phpinfo() page there is no sign of APC extension... ( of course after restarting the server !)
Where did I go wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Restart the server and check in the PHP Extension if you find php_apc